# Node.js Knex and mySQL - ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, knex.js

I am trying to create simple web app to receive dog adoption applications.

I succesfully run migrations and seeds and by doing so created these two tables:

[image]

The problem is that when I try to create new application using GUI, I get the below error:

{"response":"Error in database ForeignKeyViolationError: insert into `applications` (`doggo_name`, `email`, `name`, `phone`) values ('Coco', 'sam.do@gmail.com', 'Sam Do', '+12345667') - ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dog_adoption`.`applications`, CONSTRAINT `applications_doggo_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`doggo_id`) REFERENCES `doggos` (`id`))"}

This is second day I am trying to figure out what is wrong. Please see my code:

MIGRATION FILE:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {

    return knex.schema
        .createTable('doggos', (table) => {
            table.increments('id').notNullable();
            table.string('doggo').notNullable();
            table.integer('age').notNullable();
            table.string('breed').notNullable();
            table.string('picture').notNullable();
        })
        .createTable('applications', (table) => {
            table.increments('id').notNullable();
            table.string('name').notNullable();
            table.string('email').notNullable();
            table.integer('phone').notNullable();
            table.string('doggo_name').notNullable();
            table.integer('doggo_id').unsigned().notNullable();
            table.foreign('doggo_id').references('doggos.id');
            table.dateTime('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.raw('NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            table.dateTime('created_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        });
};
```

APPLICATION seed:

```
exports.seed = function(knex) {
 
    return knex('doggos').select().then(doggos => {
        return knex('applications').insert([
  
      { name: "xxxxxxxxx", email: "peggy33@gmail.com", phone: 79187877, doggo_name: 'Coco', doggo_id: doggos.find(doggo => doggo.doggo === 'Coco').id},
      { name: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", email: "watson.dddk@gmail.com", phone: 51393129, doggo_name: 'Tyson', doggo_id: doggos.find(doggo => doggo.doggo === 'Tyson').id},
      { name: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", email: "ravsp33@gmail.com", phone: 12345678, doggo_name: 'Nicky', doggo_id: doggos.find(doggo => doggo.doggo === 'Nicky').id}
    ]);
});

};
```

HTML FORM:

```
      <form action="/apply" method="POST">
         <div class="application-container">
            <label for="name">What is your name?</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name" required>   
            <label for="email">E-mail address</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" name="email" required>
            <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="phone" name="phone" required>
            <label for="doggo_name">Name of dog you are interested with</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name of dog you are interested with" name="doggo_name" required>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='/'">Cancel</button>
         </div>
      </form>
   </body>
```

ROUTE:

```
router.post('/apply', async (req,res) => {
    const { name, email, phone, doggo_name } = req.body;
    console.log(name, email, phone, doggo_name);

    try {
   
        const submittedApplication =  await Application.query().insert({
        name, 
        email,
        phone,
        doggo_name,
        // how to pass doggo_id to the database?

    });
    return res.send({ response: `Succesfully applied for adoption. Please wait patiently for our response!`});
    
    } catch (error) {
    return res.send({ response: "Error in database " + error });
    }
});
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could look at it with a fresh eye nd give me a hand with data persistence to my 'applications' table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make the `doggo_id` not nullable, so it will get `0` as default for all existing rows instead of `NULL`.

But then you also set it as foreign key to `doggos.id`. The foreign key constraint immediately fails on all rows since they would now all reference the doggo with ID `0` which presumably doesn't exist.

You can solve that problem by making it nullable (remove `notNullable()` from `doggo_id`), which works because `NULL` means "not referencing anything at the moment" (as opposed to "referencing the doggo with ID zero"), or by setting a default of an ID that belongs to an actually existing doggo and not zero, if that makes sense in your use case.

Comment: Hi CherryDT, thank you very much for your answer. Now I am able to save new application to the database, however doggo_id is persisted as NULL, and not as an actual id from the other table as a foreign key. Do you know how should I query the database the in my route so the correct id gets saved?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You need to get the ID from the `doggos` table (not sure how, since I don't understand entirely your structure to be honest - why do you have a `doggo_name` _and_ a reference to another `doggos` table?) and set it as `doggo_id`. If it is by the name, then you would have to first query the `doggos` table to find the ID from the name and then use that ID when creating the new row.